# Maven includes wrong version of Hazelcast

Tags: maven, version, hazelcast

My pom.xml has a dependency to include HazelCast 3.8.4, but the war includes HazelCast 3.2.1 instead. Turns out BikeEmotion has a dependency on HazelCast Client 3.2.1, which is good, but HazeCast-Client in turn has a dependency on an earlier version of HazelCast, which is the 3.2.1 that I do not want.

Basically I need to be able to exclude a specific version to force it to get 3.8.4, but there does not seem to be a way to do that.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.bikeemotion</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz-hazelcast-jobstore</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-all</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Relevant links:

[Eclipse uses wrong maven dependency in launch configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062954/eclipse-uses-wrong-maven-dependency-in-launch-configuration)

[Maven loads wrong version of dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38139597/maven-loads-wrong-version-of-dependency)

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast-client/pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude specific transitive dependencies, then use the `<exclusions/>` tag within the `<dependency/>` tag.  You can find more details in the [Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

If you want to specifically manage the version of the dependencies, then use Maven's dependency management.

You can refer :

1. [Maven dependency management](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2619732/775467

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove the provided in the pom.xml. That fixed my issue. Thanks!